# Problems with Sub in vba after repeating it

Tags: vba

Hello i have problem with sub

```
Sub lab1_5()
Dim displayText As String
Do

number = InputBox("Write number: ")

For i = 1 To 9
    
    number = number * 2
    displayText = displayText & " " & number

Next i
MsgBox displayText
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("KONIEC" & vbNewLine & "Chcesz spróbować jeszcze raz?", vbYesNo)
Loop While (answer = vbYes)
End Sub
```

If i write for example 2 it shows 2 4 8 16 etc and than after clicking yes and writing another number i have previous(2 4 8 etc) and new numbers. How can i repair it so i have only new numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `displayText` to an empty string at the start of the do loop.

```
Sub lab1_5()
Dim displayText As String
Do

Number = InputBox("Write number: ")
displayText = "" '<--- this line here
For i = 1 To 9
    
    Number = Number * 2
    displayText = displayText & " " & Number

Next i
MsgBox displayText
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("KONIEC" & vbNewLine & "Chcesz spróbowac jeszcze raz?", vbYesNo)
Loop While (answer = vbYes)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working properly now.